# Get past set up page Liferay DXP 7.1

Tags: liferay, liferay-dxp, liferay-7.1

I've tried numerous ways to set up DXP but none seem to work. I've tried with MySQL and Hypersonic, restarting everything multiple times etc but I'm coming back to one of two errors.

If I set up using Hypersonic (which isn't a problem at the moment as I'm just learning) [I come to this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9pC1.png). It should show two buttons 'I Agree' and 'I Disagree'.

If I set up using MySQL, it tells me that there's an unexpected error that has occurred.

All of my JDK and JRE paths are correct as they work completely fine on the CE of Liferay but for some reason it brings back bugs on DXP.

Any suggestions of why this is happening are welcome thank you :)

Comment: before restarting, have you also cleaned the db ?

Comment: Yeah I have, I've also tried to create a new db too just so that it was empty but I still get nothing, and I have tried MySQL and Hypersonic - I assume hypersonic refreshes itself each time/creates a new db when you select the default db

Comment: hsql will refresh when the data folder is empty .. is anything in the log files ?

Comment: @André I'm not sure but I managed to come up with a solution

I changed the content of the setenv.bat file to 

set "CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false -Duser.timezone=GMT -XX:NewRatio=3 -Xms1560m -Xmx3072m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=20 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=6 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m"
set "JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%"

And I added a mysql connector to both lib directories in the tomcat and it works fine now

Comment: Although I don't think that adding the mysql connector jar file makes a difference nor does it make the mysql db work but it's worth doing just in case but here's the link just in case https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html

Thanks for trying!